# How to refresh browser cache after publish React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, browser

I have Visual Studio 2019 template .NET Core and React application. When I make some changes and run application locally, everthing is OK and I see these changes in browser. When I publish this application on external server, browser shows me old, cached version of this site. I must force browser to clear cache and reload. It refers to .js and .css files. How can I fix it?

Comment: Implement something like version number change when deploying to external server. Then put logic by checking the version number from the clients localStorage. If it doesn't match then show popup to refresh or do window.location.reload( ) on app start. This is one of the way of doing it.

Comment: It is problem, because new script with reading from localStorage needs to be refresh to. User must force clear cache too in this case. Some people working with this site at the moment

Answer (score 2):

If you use webpack for build your react app you can configure webpack config.
Just add some hash to final bandle js name:

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
}
```

it should solve browser cache problem.
more information in official documentation: [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/)

Comment: What if you're using `npm run build`?